# bash command to run a program in a new command line window

Tags: bash, scripting, command-line, terminal

I want to run a program from inside a bash script, such that it opens in a new command line window. How can I do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That really depends on the GUI you are using. Try some of the below for executing an `ls` command.

With `gnome-terminal`:

```
gnome-terminal -x bash -c "ls; bash"
```

(taken from http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/programming-9/is-command-line-invocation-of-gnome-terminal-to-run-more-than-one-command-possible-789599/)

With `xterm`:

```
xterm -e "ls; bash"
```

(taken from http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=760006).

For `konsole`, take a look here:

- http://mandrivausers.org/index.php?/topic/28128-opening-tabs-in-konsole-from-script/

or here:

- http://lwn.net/Articles/88410/

Comment: should I add terminal checks like "if [$TERM = "xterm"];then" in that case?

Comment: This will not work - e.g. I have `TERM=xterm`, but `xterm` is an unknown command, `gnome-terminal` is a right one in my case. You can do something like: `gnome-terminal -x bash -c "ls; bash" || xterm -e "ls; bash"` to first rune `gnome-terminal` and `xterm` only if it fails (note it will output "command not found") or use some more complex detection. If on one system, I wouldn't worry about that.

Answer (score 0):

`xterm -e 'program to be run'`

Your terminal may have a different switch than `-e`, but I don't know what your terminal is.